# Get the Name of a cell via its address or reference by using a function in EXCEL

Tags: excel, reference, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I searched a lot but didn't found any good answers for it!

> Is there any internal Function returning the `Name` of a cell by passing its address as a parameter?

if it's not, what is the simplest way to obtain the `name` we've defined for a cell via giving its address/reference ???

for example I defined 'test_name' as a `name` for cell `B4` which its content is: 'test'.

I want a function in excel, like : CellName(adr) and using it like **CellName(B4)** and returns '**test_name**'

Comment: I don't know about a native worksheet function but a UDF could do this easily.

Comment: how to use it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also searched a lot to find a build-in excel function, but not found anything!

you can use `UDF` (User Defined Function) to achieve a `Cell Name` in **`Excel`**

for this act, we're going to use visual-basic language (vb)

I found some good defined functions and I'll explain how to add.

> I've appended **3** types of VB **Codes** you can choose **one of them** by your own and add it.

### STEPS

---

- **FIRST, Opening the needed items**: you can see this step [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel) or follow bellow:

  - Open a new **workbook** in excel.
  - You should define the desired function in **visual basic for applications (VBA)**
  - For opening the **VB** use the short key <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
  - Add a new **Module** to your workbook.
  - a new **module window** will be opened which is used to add your code there.

---

- **SECOND, Appending the code**:

  - **Copy** just **one** of these **three** codes:

    > **1.** CellName1(cell): takes the cell address and returns the cell's name

    ```
    Public Function CellName1(cel As Range) As Variant
        Dim nm As name
            For Each nm In Names
                If nm.RefersTo = "=" & cel.Parent.name & "!" & cel.Address Then
                    CellName1 = nm.name
                    Exit Function
               End If
            Next
        CellName1 = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End Function
    ```

    > **2.** CellName2(cell): takes the cell address and returns the cell's name

    ```
    Function CellName2(cel As Range) As String
        Dim rng As Range
        On Error Resume Next

        Set rng = cel

        If Len(rng.name.name) < 0 Then
            CellName2 = "No named Range"
            Exit Function
        End If

        CellName2 = rng.name.name

        If InStr("CellName2", "!") > 0 Then
            CellName2 = Right(CellName2, Len(CellName2) - InStr(CellName2, "!"))
        End If

    End Function
    ```

    > **3.** CellName3(row,col): takes the cell row and column and returns the cell's name

    ```
    Function CellName3(r As Long, c As Long) As String
        Dim rng As Range

        Set rng = Cells(r, c)
        On Error Resume Next

        If Len(rng.name.name) < 0 Then
            CellName3 = "No named Range"
            Exit Function
        End If

        CellName3 = rng.name.name

    End Function
    ```

don't forget to save the function you've pasted!

---

---

### Examples

consider cell **B4** that has a name: "test_name", now you can get it's name by each functions defined above...

[image: image 1]

now assume another cell like **D7**.

we use the first function (`CellName1`) for this cell and for the result, the name of the 'B4' cell will be the content of 'D7'

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

so, we passed `B4` to the function as the parameter and obtained its name as the content of 'D7' cell.

```
CellName1(B4)
```

or

```
CellName2(B4)
```

or

```
CellName3(4,2)
```